# iTunes cutting off songs

Tags: itunes, music

iTunes cut them off and move onto the next song, usually after a minute.Some tracks plays fine until end some have this problem. The songs all play fine in any other media player. I'm on Yosemite and the latest version of iTunes. I have a friend that has the same problem. He has more than 10k song, i have more than 9k. 
Is there anyway I can fix this? Anyone having the same problem? Thanks

Comment: I get this too.. there's a thread somewhere on askdifferent that relates (can't find it now) but the best convo on the topic I've read is https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/39s6vn/itunes_cutting_off_recently_added_songs/

Comment: @ptim I exported the library and imported using the xml file. It's still working now after several months.